# Dynamically Generating Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-select, dynamically-generated

I need help with this dynamically generated dropdown options. What I am trying to accomplish is have three dynamically generated dropdown menus that are dependent on each other. I can get the first dropdown to be created just fine, but my main issue is that I cannot get the onchange to fire when something new is selected.

```
var dropDown = document.createElement("FIELDSET");  
var course_s = document.createElement("SELECT");
course_s.id  = "course";
for(var j = 0; j < courseList.length+1; j++){
    var course_o = document.createElement("OPTION");
    if(j == 0){
        course_o.value = "NONE";
        course_o.innerHTML = "NONE";
    }else{
        course_o.value = courseList[j-1];
        course_o.innerHTML = courseTitle[j-1]+" "+courseNumber[j-1];
    }
    course_s.appendChild(course_o);
}

var module_s  = document.createElement("SELECT");
module_s.id   = "module";
var module_o = document.createElement("OPTION");
module_o.value = "NONE";
module_o.innerHTML = "NONE";
module_s.appendChild(module_o);

var segment_s = document.createElement("SELECT");
segment_s.id  = "segment";
var segment_o = document.createElement("OPTION");
segment_o.value = "NONE";
segment_o.innerHTML = "NONE";
segment_s.appendChild(segment_o);
```

Module and segment options are set when course has been changed.

Comment: The dropdown options are all dynamically generated. They are only made using document.createElement().

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. If you add your code then the question can be awnsered in the best way that fits.